# Construct an object by indirect variable reference within namespaces

Tags: php, instantiation, indirect-objects

I want PHP to construct an object by indirect variable reference within namespaces.
It goes like:

```
$ArticleObjectIdentifier = 'qmdArticle\excursions_list_item';
$result = new $ArticleObjectIdentifier($parent_obj,$r);
```

Where qmdArticle is a namespace used and excursions_list_item
is the class name - which is usually not hardcoded but read from DB.

I get the following error - when using the above:

```
Class 'qmdArticle\\excursions_list_item' not found in /media/work/www/mytestarea/control.php on line 1916 ...
```

index.php

```
  <?php
namespace hy_soft\qimanfaya\testarea\main;

use hy_soft\qimanfaya\testarea\articles as article;

include_once('article.php');
$ArticleLoader = 'article\excursions_list_item';
$article = new $ArticleLoader();
$article->showcontent();


?>
```

article.php

```
<?php namespace hy_soft\qimanfaya\testarea\articles

  class excursions_list_item {  private $content;       function
 __construct()  {
          $this->content = 'This is the article body';

         // parent::__construct($parent,$dbrBaseRec);
            }

    public function showcontent()   {       echo $this->content;    } } 
?>
```

Comment: Well this is a first, I've never seen variable variables used for class names. From what the error shows, PHP seems to escape the \ character.

Comment: It will take some time to provide a complete sample.

Comment: Probably tomorrow. 21st

Comment: @Paul Crovella, I have added a sample. If I run it without namespaces it works.

Answer (score 0):

I finally have found a similar example but it took a while until I actually got it:

The actual trick is using double quotes: >>"<<
AND double-slashes >>\<<
AND it doesn't work with an alias created like

```
use hy_soft\qimanfaya\testarea\articles as article;
```

You have to use the fully qualified class name (FQCN)

```
$ArticleLoader = "\\hy_soft\\qimanfaya\\testarea\articles\\excursions_list_item";
```

I would still apreciate any advice how to do it with an alias. Thanks.

Working example:
article.php

```
<?php
namespace hy_soft\qimanfaya\testarea\articles;

class excursions_list_item
{
    private $content;

    function __construct()
    {
         $this->content = 'This is the article body';

        // parent::__construct($parent,$dbrBaseRec);

    }

    public function showcontent()
    {
        echo $this->content;
    }
}
?>
```

index.php

```
<?php
namespace hy_soft\qimanfaya\testarea\main;

use hy_soft\qimanfaya\testarea\articles as article;

include_once('article.php');
$ArticleLoader = "\\hy_soft\\qimanfaya\\testarea\articles\\excursions_list_item";
//$ArticleLoader = "\\article\\excursions_list_item"; doesn't work
$article = new $ArticleLoader();
$article->showcontent();


?>
```